# How to set category Is Anchor default to yes for all categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am trying to set category Is Anchor default to yes  for all categories 
I tried these database queries

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51;
```

query run successfully but no effect in categories

try this

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_int` set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51 and parent_id <> 0
```

return error

```
error:#1146 - Table 'magento1.catalog_category_int' doesn't exist
```

and try with this
create new file in magento root directory with this code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Load Up Magento Core
define('MAGENTO', realpath(''));

require_once(MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php');

$app = Mage::app();

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('is_anchor', 0)
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 1))
 ->setOrder('entity_id')
 ;

foreach($categories as $category) {
 echo $category->getId() . "\t" . $category->getName() . "\n";
 $category->setIsAnchor(1);
 $category->save();
}
```

but no result
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 9):

You can do this as a single sql statement:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int 
SET    value = 1 
WHERE  attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                       FROM   eav_attribute 
                       WHERE  attribute_code = 'is_anchor' 
                       LIMIT  1);
```

Comment: It helped to me. +1

Answer (score 5):

First identify the attribute id of the is_anchor attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = ‘is_anchor’;
```

Get the attribute id (for me is 43).
Now run the following query

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 43;
```

replace 43 with your own attribute id.
After this, just rebuild these indexes: category flat data, product category association, url rewrites.
[taken from CodersKick](http://blog.coderskick.com/magento-set-category-is-anchor-yes/)

Comment: The link to blog.coderskick.com is broken, but looking at Google Cache, the answer is an exact copy of what used to be on that website.

Answer (score 3):

Fire this query from database . you get attribute_code.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor';
```

we Get attribute id 51 in my database. Now Fire this query

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51;
```

replace 51 with your own attribute id. And just rebuild these indexes

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are wrong. For a new category there is no is_anchor attribute set, so you cant update it. You have to find the non existing categories and insert is_anchor attribute values for them.

Solution (quick shot):

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Cartware_Import_Shell_Compiler extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Run script
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

        $categoryTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category');
        $eavAttributeTable = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute');
        $eavAttributeIntCategoryTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_int');

        //fetch is anchor attribute_id
        $query = "SELECT attribute_id 
                    FROM   {$eavAttributeTable}
                    WHERE  attribute_code = 'is_anchor'
                    LIMIT  1";

        $id = $writeConnection->fetchOne($query);

        //update all categories to is_anchor = 1
        $query = "UPDATE {$eavAttributeIntCategoryTable} SET value = 1 WHERE attribute_id = {$id}";
        $writeConnection->query($query);

        //fetch all catgegory ids that are is_anchor = 1
        $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM {$eavAttributeIntCategoryTable} WHERE attribute_id = {$id} AND value = 1";
        $results = $writeConnection->fetchAll($query);
        $idsWithAnchor = array();

        foreach ($results as $key => $value){

            $idsWithAnchor[] = $value['entity_id'];

        }

        //fetch all category ids that have no is_anchor attribute set (default)
        $idsWithAnchorFormatted = implode(",", $idsWithAnchor);
        $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM {$categoryTable} WHERE entity_id NOT IN ($idsWithAnchorFormatted)";
        $results = $writeConnection->fetchAll($query);

        //insert all is_anchor attributes that are not existing
        foreach ($results as $key => $value){

            $entity_id = $value['entity_id'];
            $query = "INSERT INTO {$eavAttributeIntCategoryTable}(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) VALUES(3, {$id}, 0, {$entity_id}, 1)";

            echo $query . PHP_EOL;

            //$writeConnection->query($query);
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Cartware_Import_Shell_Compiler();
$shell->run();
```